# Populating textbox ng attributes from within directive

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, angularjs

A JSFiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DfLdF/

The problem description is as follows, I have a controller wrapping a form which contains some logic, and can not be defined within the directive hash as controller:

I need the ability to populate a field from a directive dynamically like so:

```
 App.Directive.SomeAwesomeDirective = ->
     restrict: 'C'

     link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
         someValue = scope.someValue
         field = element.find(".some-class")
         scope.fieldValue = someValue
         field.ngModel = "scope.fieldValue"
         field.ngClass = "scope.someAwesomeClass"

         monitorFields = (newValue, oldValue) ->
              console.log "we are here"
              console.debug newValue
              console.debug oldValue
              scope.addValue(newValue)

         scope.$watch "scope.fieldValue", monitorFields, true
```

I need the following to be fulfilled:

1) When the textfields value is changed, I want scope.fieldValue to be updated.
2) After this happens, I want the addValue method (defined on the wrapping controller), to be called with the new value for validation.
3) The addValue method should set the someAwesomeClass scope variable, and the input fields class should update.
4) The ngClasses to be applied are ng-valid/ng-invalid. Form validation should function correctly in correspondence with these classes

As can be seen in my jsfiddle, none of these things are currently happening, and I am unsure as to why...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by defining a directive `someClass`, which will execute the function on its parent. The `form` tag gets an extra attribute `execute`, which holds the function to execute. The `someClass` directive will search the controller of `dir` directive (hence require: '^dir') and execute it.

Another solution would have been to drop the `dir` directive and define the `execute` attribute on the `someClass` directive (e.g. when each input field should trigger a different function).

```
<form class="dir" execute="someFunction">
```

**Directives:**

```
app.directive('dir', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
      execute: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      this.execute = $scope.execute;
    }
  };
});


app.directive('someClass', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    require: '^dir',
    replace: true,
    template: '<INPUT name="foo" id="bar" type="text" ng-model="fieldValue" >',
    scope: {
      fieldValue: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      var monitorField = function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue) {
           ctrl.execute(newValue);
        }
      };
      scope.$watch("fieldValue", monitorField, true);
    }
  };
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/wayzL/).